# How To Get File Path From IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, ihttphandler

```js
function uploadFile(Data, data) {


  $.ajax({
    url: "AdminUploadHandler.ashx?Type=" + Data,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(result) {

      alert(result);

    },
    error: function(err) {

      showErrMsg("Error In fileUpload.", "alert-danger", 0);

    }
  });
}
```

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                string fileName = VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(context.Request.Url.LocalPath);
                context.Response.Write("0");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Write("3");
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogging c = new ExceptionLogging("Admin  Upload Failed", ex);
            c.ErrorLog(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/Logs/"));

        }
    }
```

i am using ihttphandler
i want physical path of uploaded file for example D:\upload i am able to get file name from  HttpFileCollection files but not the path how to get file path 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: You want to the the path the file was uploaded from? You can't. Browsers will not tell you this, for security reasons.

Comment: ok thanks for the response